# Combine SQL fields and Convert from bit to readable sentence

Tags: sql

If, for example, I had two fields such as 'Dog' and 'Cat' that defines whether a person has a dog or cat; and, they are bit types. And, I wanted to combine these fields for each person to say something like USER, 'has a dog and a cat' such as the following:-

SQL original --

```
select username, dog, cat from table
username   dog    cat
john       1      0
tim        1      1
```

SQL with combined --??

```
username   petstatus
john       'has a dog but no cat'
tim        'has a dog and a cat'
```

Does anybody have any ideas on what would be the best way to achieve this type of functionality using SQL. Or, where can I get a copy of similar functionality.

Thanks,

Ric.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
 select username, 
       case when dog = 1 and cat = 1 then 'has a dog and a cat' 
       when dog = 1 and cat = 0 then 'has a dog but no cat' 
       when dog = 0 and cat = 1 then 'has a cat but no dog' 
       when dog = 0 and cat = 0 then 'has a no cat and no dog' end as petstatus
from table
```

**UPDATE :** For more than 2 columns dynamically, you need to set text as like readable sentence by this way :

```
select username, 'has' +  
        replace(replace(dog,'1',' a dog'),'0',' no dog') +
        replace(replace(cat,'1',' a cat'),'0',' no cat') 
from table
```

Comment: There are many more fields than just dog and cat this was just an example so to do that for all the possibilities is not feasible.

Comment: I would need something more like single if statements to append onto the one field

Comment: Then you need to think about dynamic query for that.

Comment: I am sure I will find what you have given me useful for other queries but I have found out that I can return the result using a function that is executed as part of a query. So select username, function(username) from table, function will then return a combined result using if statements.